# Which classes of matrices contain $A$ and which contain $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

> **14**. In the list below, which classes of matrices contain $A$ and which contain $B$?
>
> $$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
>         0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>         0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>         0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>         1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>         \end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \textrm{and}\ \ \ B = \frac14\begin{bmatrix}
>         1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   *Orthogonal*, *invertible*, *projection*, *permutation*, *Hermitian*, *rank-$1$*, *diagonalizable*, *Markov*. Find the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

I am pretty confused about classes; I don't know what it means, so I can't really do part A and I need your help with it?

For part B, I got all eigenvalues are $1$ for matrix $A$, and $0$ for matrix $B$. Is this what you get?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused too. what is your question? do you want to know how to find eigenvalues?

Comment: They just mean, "Is $A$ orthogonal, invertible, a projection, etc.?"  And the same for $B$.

Comment: shabbeh, just checking whether am correct for part B. For part A, as of now I don't understand how to proove whether its a projection  or not